# Swift UITableView delete selected row and any rows above it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My TableView contains cells that represent a mileage log. I need to allow users that ability to delete any mistakes. The tableview lists the logs in descending order. Deleting the top row is OK. Deleting any other row I need to issue a warning as an alert and if confirmed then delete the selected row + all rows above it. Is this possible? Is there any example code anywhere?

**UPDATE**

Based on the two answers I have had so far I have done the following....

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MileageLogsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var milageLogTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to fetch MileageLog")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }

        // Display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MileageLog")

        // Add Sort Descriptors
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tripDate", ascending: false)
        let mileSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startMileage", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort, mileSort]

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext

        // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "rootCache")

        //ADDED AS PER ANSWER FROM SANDEEP
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController

    }()


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            return sections.count
        }

        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            let sectionInfo = sections[section]
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
        }

        return 0
    } 

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MileageLogCell") as! MileageTableViewCell

        // Fetch MileageLog
        if let mileageLog = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MileageLog {
            //format date as medium style date
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
            let logDateString = formatter.stringFromDate(mileageLog.tripDate!)
            //format NSNumber mileage to string
            let mileageInt:NSNumber = mileageLog.startMileage!
            let mileageString = String(mileageInt)

            cell.lb_LogDate.text = logDateString
            cell.lb_LogMileage.text = mileageString
            cell.lb_LogStartLocation.text = mileageLog.startLocation
            cell.lb_LogDestination.text = mileageLog.endLocation
        }
        return cell
     }


    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: Fetched Results Controller Delegate Methods
    func controllerWillChangeContent(fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
            case .Insert:
                break;
            case .Delete:

                let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
                if let indexPath = indexPath {

                    if indexPath.row == 0 {
                        //this is the top (first row)
                        // Deleting without warning
                        let objectToDelete = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
                        context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData();

                    } else {
                        //we are deleted a row that is not the top row
                        // we need to give a warning and if acknowledged then delele all rows from the selected row and all rows above it

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure? This will remove this and all logs above it.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

                        }
                        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default) { (action) in

                            for deleteindex in 0 ... indexPath.row {
                                let deleteIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: deleteindex, inSection: 0)
                                let objectToDelete = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(deleteIndexPath) as! NSManagedObject
                                context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData();
                        }
                        alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

                        // Dispatch on the main thread
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
                            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
                        }

                    }
                }
                break;
            case .Update:
                break;
            case .Move:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Now my problem is that the touching Delete does nothing. The treeview is correctly populated. The Edit button is in the navbar. Click Edit and the 'no entry' icon appear on each row... slide a row and the Delete block appears. Click delete and nothing...! What have I missed out?

**FINAL WORKING FIX**

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch editingStyle {

     case .Delete:
        let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                //this is the top (first row)
                // Deleting without warning
                let indexPathToDelete = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                let objectToDelete = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPathToDelete) as! NSManagedObject
                context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    //self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                //self.tableView.reloadData();

            } else {
                //we are deleted a row that is not the top row
                // we need to give a warning and if acknowledged then delele all rows from the selected row and all rows above it

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure? This will remove this and all logs above it.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

                }
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default) { (action) in

                    for deleteindex in 0 ... indexPath.row {
                        let deleteIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: deleteindex, inSection: 0)
                        let objectToDelete = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(deleteIndexPath) as! NSManagedObject
                        context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)

                    }

                    do {
                        try context.save()

                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

                // Dispatch on the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
                }

            }
        break;

    default :
        return
    }

}

// MARK: Fetched Results Controller Delegate Methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        break;
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        break;
    case .Move:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need example for that buddy?? just delete the rows from your data source and reload the tableview :) thats all :)

Comment: I'm new to iOS and swift so I may be missing something... TableView has edit button in navbar. User clicks edit then selects the row and clicks delete. This will delete that row. All good so far... what I need is an addition to this where the code will not only delete the selected row but also all rows above it.

Comment: You don't delete from the uitableview, you delete from the datasource, then call tableView.reloadData().

Comment: You should add the code where you perform the deletion.

Comment: :) Dont worry will help you :) is your data source is getting populated from coredata or a local array ???

Comment: Thanks... data is in core data. using NSFetchedResultsController (If I can get it to work)... see my other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849074/swift-uitableview-delete-row-item-tableview-datasource-is-core-data

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo my code can be seen in my other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849074/swift-uitableview-delete-row-item-tableview-datasource-is-core-data I can place it here too if this helps

Comment: @mych : Gimme 10 min mate :) lemme post the answer :)

Comment: Instead of using `commitEditingStyle`, you should use `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` available since iOS 8. Wait for the answer ;)

Comment: Sandeep and Michaël, thanks for your help... I will try out your suggestions later and let you know how I get on. I suspect I will use a combination of your answers as Sandeep you are using NSFetchedResultsController but Michaël has included the check for top row and if not issue alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the enhancement to use edit actions this is the easy solution.

First of all **do not touch** the delegate method `didChangeObject`.
Leave it as it is. It is called after making changes in the managed object context and works like the view in the MVC pattern.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
        case .move:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Insert the code to delete the rows in `commitEditingStyle` which works like the model in the MVC pattern. The code deletes all rows from the selected row above in the current section.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .delete:
      let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
      let section = indexPath.section
      let currentRow = indexPath.row
      for index in 0...currentRow {
          let indexPathToDelete = IndexPath(row: index, section: section)
          let objectToDelete = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPathToDelete) as! NSManagedObject
          context.delete(objectToDelete)
      }
      do {
        try context.save()
      } catch {
        print(error)
      }
      
    case .insert, .none: break
    }
  }
```

Comment: Vadian, many thanks... I've placed an update which now incorporates the alert if more than one row will be deleted... Thanks to Michaël's for his help with that....

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe what you can do :)

Knowing that you have already sorted your data using fetchedResultsController sort predicate :) now all you have to do is to delete all the rows from 0 to row the user has selected :)

Because you have only one section and all cell will have section as "0" in their index path :) all you have to do is to iterate from 0 to row number of the cell selected :)

create a indexpath with iterated value as row and "0" as section :) fetch the object from fetchedResultsController and delete it in a loop :)

Once done reload the tableView :)

Refering to your previous question :)

```
case .Delete:
        // Delete the row from the data source

        let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        for deleteindex in 0 ... indexPath.row {
                var deleteIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: deleteindex, inSection: 0)
                let objectToDelete = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(deleteIndexPath) as! NSManagedObject
               context.deleteObject(objectToDelete)
        }
        do {
          try context.save()
          self.tableView.reloadData();
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
```

**EDIT**

As per your updated question, none of the fetchedResults controller delegates are getting called.

That's because, you haven't told fetchedResults controller whom to inform when something happens in DB. What I meant is you have not set the delegate of fetchedResults controller to self buddy :)

*copy pasting your own code with modification and comment*

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MileageLog")

        // Add Sort Descriptors
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tripDate", ascending: false)
        let mileSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startMileage", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort, mileSort]

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext

        // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "rootCache")

        //set the delegate to self here. You have confirmed the fetchedResultsController delegate in interface remember ??
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController

    }()
```

Hope I answerred your question :) Have a doubt ? Leave a comment below :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: @Mych : Sure buddy :) I have concentrated only on deleting the managed object's from core data :) You can use Michaël Azevedo's code for handling the UI :) All the best :)

Comment: Sandeep... please see my code that I have based on Michaël's and your code. I have something missing as the delete action is not triggered.

Comment: What do you mean by delete action not trigerred buddy ??? is your didChangeObject delegate getting called ?? Is your alert being displayed ???

Comment: Neither. Click the delete block in a row and didChangeObject is not getting called... so I'm not getting as far as the alert.

Comment: @mych : hehehehehehe :) have you set fetchedResultsController.delegate = self ???? set it in  fetchedResultsController getter before return statement :)

Comment: @Mych : see the updated answer :) getter for fetchedResultsController modified to set self as delegate :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110434/discussion-between-mych-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method of [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:) protocol, available since iOS 8.0.

> **Return Value**
>
> An array of UITableViewRowAction objects representing the actions for the row. Each action you provide is used to create a button that the user can tap.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Use this method when you want to provide custom actions for one of your table rows. When the user swipes horizontally in a row, the table view moves the row content aside to reveal your actions. Tapping one of the action buttons executes the handler block stored with the action object.

Here is an example of implementation

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // Deleting without warning

        // The closure will be called when tapping on the action
        let deleteClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in    

            // Delete the first object
            // you can animate it with the BeginUpdates... EndUpdates too             
            self.dataSourceArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      
        // Default style is Destructive
        return [UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: deleteClosure)]
    }
    else  {
        // Deleting with warning

        // The closure will be called when tapping on the action
        let deleteClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in    

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: Localization(kStr_NotifDisabled), preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
                
            }
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default) { (action) in
                        
                self.dataSourceArray(Range(start: 0, end: indexPath.row))    
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
                   
            // Dispatch on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
            }
        }          
        // Default style is Destructive
        return [UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: deleteClosure)]
    }            
}
```

Comment: Michaël... please see my code that I have based on Sandeep's and your code. I have something missing as the delete action is not triggered.

Comment: Just seeing it now at wake, let me look at it :)

Comment: Where are you handling the deletion of the item in your tableview ? You have to implement either `commitEditingStyle` or `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method to handle it .

Comment: Good morning... I'm at work now.. My whole code is above so if I have something missing then it just shows that I'm very new (my first project) and my background is .net Vb so steep learning curve. My plan was for a simple app but I then notice I need to account for all sorts of human possibilities like being able to delete mistakes!. Any advise/help would be appreciated. My app is almost complete its just this core data code that has been a struggle to get into my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
return true
```

}

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
  arrRecordList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)    
  tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

}
```

}

Comment: As far as I can see this would delete the row from TableView but not from the Core Data (datasource)

Comment: yes Mych ,it would delete row and data from array ,not Core Data. you have to update your Core Data